# I can't get fetch to put the data from formData into the POST array for my php file to read and send to server

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch

For background: I'm using Xampp to make a localhost website. I'm using it to also host my database and currently I'm trying to make code that allows me to update the quiz information. But the issue is nothing is being put into the POST array. Before I show the code I want to make it clear: I checked the formData, it has all the data in it correctly. I checked networks payload and it shows all the data correctly. But when I do var_dump($_REQUEST); and var_dump($_POST); there's nothing. I'm honestly lost because it looks like everything is working (note: on another file I did this and its not putting anything in post but for some reason it still updates the database).

//javascript code that handles the request

```
function saveQuiz() {
    const quizID = "<?php echo $quizid; ?>";
    const quizName = document.getElementById("quiz_name").value;

    const formData = new URLSearchParams();
    formData.append('quizName', quizName);
    formData.append('quizID', quizID);

    const questionTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.question-text');

    // Loop through the question texts and append them to formData
    questionTexts.forEach((textarea, index) => {
        formData.append(`question_texts[${index}]`, textarea.value);
    });

    console.log('FormData:', formData);
    for (const pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
    }//prints everything correctly

    fetch('updateQuiz.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('submitted', response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('error: ', error);
    });

    window.location.href = "../quiz/quizzesOverviewFaculty.php";
}
```

//updateQuiz.php file that handles the php portion:

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "course_resource_library";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";

//Creating connection to database
$conn = mysqli_connect(
    hostname: $host,
    username: $dbusername,
    password: $dbpassword,
    database: $dbname
);

if ($conn) {
    $quizID = $_POST['quizID'];
    $quizName = $_POST['quizName'];
  

    // Update the database with the new names
    $query = "UPDATE quiz SET quiz_name='$quizName' WHERE quiz_ID='$quizID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    //Retrieve question IDs and texts sent from the client-side
    $questionIDs = $_POST['question_ids'];
    $questionTexts = $_POST['question_texts'];

    // Check if the arrays have the same length
    if (count($questionIDs) === count($questionTexts)) {
        // Loop through the question IDs and texts
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($questionIDs); $i++) {
            $questionID = $questionIDs[$i];
            $questionText = $questionTexts[$i];

            $updateQuery = "UPDATE questions SET question = '$questionText' WHERE question_ID = '$questionID'";
        }

        // Check if the update was successful
        if ($conn->query($updateQuery) === TRUE) {
            // Successful update
            echo "Question with ID: $questionID updated successfully<br>";
        } else {
            // Failed to update
            echo "Error updating question with ID: $questionID - " . $conn->error . "<br>";
        }
    }
  
    if ($result) {
        // Update successful
        echo "Name updated successfully";
        echo $quizID;
        echo "  ";
        echo $quizName;
    } 
    else {
        // Error in updating
        echo "Error updating name: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} 
else {
    echo "error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

//here the html that gets the data from

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <!-- This creates the thing in the middle that holds the info -->
    <div class="card h-4">
        <div class="card-header text-dark" style = "background-color:#CEB888">
                <div>
                    <span style="font-size: x-large; margin-left: 20px;"><b>Quiz Name: </b></span>
                    <input type="text" id="quiz_name" name="quiz_name" required="Yes" style="font-size: large;" value="<?php echo $quiz_name; ?>"> 
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="card h-100 w-100">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!-- Loop through number of questions -->
                            <?php
                                // Assuming you have already retrieved questions and answers from the database
                                // Repeat the loop for however many questions are in the quiz
                                foreach ($data as $row) {
                                    $questionId = $row["question_ID"];
                                    $questionText = $row["question"];
                                    ?>

                                    <!-- Display questions using html -->
                                    <h5 class="card-title text-dark">Question <?php echo $questionId; ?></h5>
                                    <p class="card-text text-dark"></p>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea class="form-control question-text" rows="5" name="questions[<?php echo $questionId; ?>]"><?php echo $questionText; ?></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <span style="font-size: large; color: grey;">Answers:</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row"> 
                                        <!--<input type="hidden" name="question_ids[]" value="<?php //echo $row["question_ID"]; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="question_texts[]" value="<?php //echo $row["question"]; ?>">-->
                                        <!-- Use php to get the current answer questions -->
                                        <?php
                                            //repeat the loop for however many answers there are
                                            foreach ($data2 as $row2) {
                                                $answerId = $row2["question_ID"];
                                                $answerText = $row2["answer_option"];
                                                if($answerId === $questionId) {
                                                    ?>
                            
                                                    <!-- Use html to display radio buttons and answers -->
                                                    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

                                                    <!-- This will make sure the correct answer is selected -->
                                                    <?php
                                                    // check to see if current answer is the correct answer
                                                    if($row2["correct_answer"] == "yes")
                                                    {
                                                        ?>
                                                        <input type="radio" id="answer_<?php echo $answerId; ?>" name="question_<?php echo $questionId; ?>" value="<?php echo $answerId; ?>" required checked>
                                                        <?php
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        ?>
                                                        <input type="radio" id="answer_<?php echo $answerId; ?>" name="question_<?php echo $questionId; ?>" value="<?php echo $answerId; ?>" required="required">
                                                        <?php
                                                    }
                                                    ?> 
                            
                                                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                                                    <input type="text" id="quiz_name" name="quiz_name" required="Yes" value="<?php echo $answerText; ?>" >
                                
                                                    <!-- End loop that goes through the questions -->
                                                    <?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- End the big php loop -->
                                    <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <!-- Buttons at the bottom of the page -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light btn mr-2" href="#" style="background-color:#0C8CE9; height: 30pt;"><b>Create Next Question</b></a>
                        <a class="nav-link text-light btn mr-2" style="background-color:#0C8CE9; height: 30pt;" onclick="saveQuiz()"><b>Save and Post</b></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light btn" href="quizzesOverviewFaculty.php" style="background-color:#F54545; height: 30pt;"><b>Cancel</b></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Buttons at bottom of page -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know its connecting correctly because its able to get the data from the database for the values for the user to actually update so I'm so confused on why it won't put anything in the POST array. I'm stuck and need some new eyes to look at this and help me figure out the issue. If anyone can help me figure this out it would be appreciated!!

Comment: try to change `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  to `application/json` in your fetch method

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth Just tried it, nothing changed. It still shows POST as empty.

Comment: try to `stringify` your formData: `body: formData` to `body: JSON.stringify(formData)`

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth, nope doesn't change anything.

Comment: `const formData = new FormData();` if you want to send FormData

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried that first (sorry should have mentioned it) but I get the same results when I do it like that as well.

Comment: have you checked the browser console to see what the POST is sending in the body? If it's sending the right thing, at least you can stop worrying about the javascript side and concentrate on PHP

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah I checked that, and it is actually sending the data correctly, just for some reason the php file says there's nothing in POST.

Comment: try without `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`

Comment: @JaromandaX still shows as empty.

Comment: are you sure you arrive at the correct php file?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth yeah, networks shows its opening / going to updateQuiz.php

Comment: `php file that handles the php portion`...which file is that, exactly? I assume it's `updateQuiz.php`?

Comment: BTW your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and syntax errors. I'm not sure who would have taught you to write it like that, but they shouldnt have done. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement to learn the secure and reliable way to build your SQL queries using PHP

Comment: @ADyson I'm new at this and this is just for a school project (a software engineering class where we take an old teams code and basically add on to it so this is the first time I'm actually working with connecting to a database and what not - and because its a local host only we don't need to worry about security yet. But thanks I'll look into it more!)

Comment: @ADyson yes the php file is the updateQuiz.php, technically the file that the html and JavaScript code is in is also a php file because its gets the quiz information from the database for the user to even be able to see what they want to edit. Could that somehow mess things up?

Comment: Maybe it's just for school, but a) you still shouldn't get into bad habits, and b) no-one should have taught you this technique in the first place. Doing it properly isn't any more difficult, and in fact it reduces the risk of silly beginner mistakes such as syntax errors caused by incorrectly quoted variables. (e.g. Imagine a question or answer text value containing an apostrophe...currently that would crash your SQL (because the apostrophe would be seen to terminate the string in SQL earlier than you wanted it to). Parameterised queries don't suffer from ridiculous problems like that.)

Comment: Anyway I just tested your HTML/JS code on my machine, and the updateQuiz code (only as far as the var_dump($_REQUEST) since i don't have your database) and I can see from the Network tool that it submits the data to updateQuiz correctly and that the var_dump comes back correct in the Network tool (I proved this by viewing the Response tab of the call to updateQuiz.php). So unless there's some JS or PHP error you haven't mentioned then it would seem that this code isn't a [mre] of your issue, and there's not much we can do to help you on that basis unfortunately.

Comment: The file containing the HTML being also a PHP doesn't make any difference, no. We don't know what quizzesOverviewFaculty.php obviously, but that should be completely irrelevant to what the the AJAX post to updateQuiz.php, since the AJAX request occurs before the redirect to quizzesOverviewFaculty.php. Having said that, your code doesn't wait for the AJAX request to complete before redirecting to another page, which is a bit risky

Comment: @ADyson sorry I wasn't clear, what I meant by mentioning it was for school is that no one taught me anything, this is all from researching and looking at the previous teams code, but I get what you mean I'll try to work on that more as I get more practice in on this subject.

Comment: I guess if the code was very old it might have been badly written this way, and there are unfortunately quite a  few dodgy tutorials online which demonstrate bad habits too.

Comment: @ADyson anyway, this is straight up all the code but the php at the top that gets the data from the database (which works perfectly fine and I have tried removing it to see if that was the issue and it wasn't) and the links for some bootstrap html css stuff. Honestly I'm starting to feel like the issue has to do with Xampp because its extremely unstable at least from my groups experience - two of us had to completely remove it from our computers and redownload to even start the sql server. Either way thanks for the help!

Comment: Well I justed it on my own local xampp-generated environment and it was fine. Bear in mind that xampp is basically a glorified installer anyway - your code actually runs using your browser and the php engine, which is the same no matter how you install it

Comment: @ADyson yeah the only reason I have the code set to directly go to a new page right after was to do some test and I was planning on later (if time allowed) to try and look into ways of making that better. Also yeah no the code was not written well and is honestly a huge mess so I expected a lot of issues with it (less than I thought to be honest lol).

Comment: If you comment out that last redirect line does it make any difference? I'd hope not, but I guess it's worth a try

Comment: @ADyson ah gotcha, then maybe its something with my computer? I know one group members computer wasn't actually reading her most updated data for a little while, not sure why.

Comment: @ADyson no when I comment it out nothing changes - I did that multiple times while trying to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax instead of Fetch:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'updateQuiz.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the ajax code. If you think there is, please explain why you think so, and why this code would be better. Just dumping code with "use this" as the only commentary isn't a useful answer, generally. See also [answer]